AB test design in eCommerce - group split per user and statistic aggregation per item
Is it statistically correct/viable to run an A/B test where the split into groups is per user (randomly assigned) and the statistic is aggregated per store item?
Lets narrow down the issue into a specific example: 

Setting: An online shop where multiple companies post items that users can purchase. Companies can purchase addons that boost item positioning on the website.
Goal: Increase the fraction of items that reached a specific addon click-through target (e.g. 5%)
Test: We're dealing with a binomial distribution so Fisher's exact test was chosen. Especially that there aren't that many items so the test shouldn't be computationally exhausting. The users are split randomly into 50/50 percent groups upon their website entry via a cookie:

Group A: status quo. Nothing changed on the website
Group B: a new system/algorithm affecting the item positioning on the website



Example data:
Addon click-through target: 5%




Count items that reached target
Count items that didn't reach target




group A
5216
1295


group B
5558
953



Fisher's exact p-value is less than 0.0001 -> results statistically significant for alpha=0.05.
My concern is that such methodology (group split by users, aggregation by items) violates some assumptions of AB test design and theory. We ran 300 AA fisher exact tests with alpha=0.05 and out of those 300 simulations 4% (12 out of 300) were statistically significant.
I tried looking online for articles that employed such methodology but I was unable to find relevant sources given the overflow of "AB test tutorials" (maybe my search skills suck). I asked GenAI and the model doesn't seem to have a problem with such approach but... it's GenAI.
Can anyone elaborate on this? Any relevant sources or links?

Welcome to CV. A priori I see nothing wrong with your approach, and you established that group B more often reaches the threshold for add-on click-through. Can you clarify however how subjects are assigned to groups A and B?

Hi @jginestet! Thanks for the welcome. Happy to clarify - subjects (users) are split into groups A and B via a cookie upon their entry on the website (page view)

There is still something missing. Are A users different in any aspect from B users, or randomly assigned? Or do A users see a different design than B users? What is the "treatment" difference between A & B which could lead you to expect that more addons would be clicked?

Users are assigned into groups A and B at random (50/50 percent split). Group A is the current system (status quo) whereas group B employs a change in the system which is supposed to help the items reach a given addon click-through target

Your design is fine as you have described (you may want to edit your original question to add the various details you submitted in the comments; readers do not always read all the comments...).
You were worried that your study design would have an "A/B group split per user". But it does not; the users in group A are not selected based on some user attribute, but instead are randomly assigned to 2 different designs of your system. You also were worried about the outcome variable to be "aggregated per store item". But it is not so, or rather, while you look at each item, and see if it reached the threshold, you are then further aggregating per design.
This is a very general A/B test design; you randomly assign users to A or B, then look at some outcome variable, and see if there is a difference based on the randomly assigned design.
The one caveat about your design is the dichotomization of the outcome: above some arbitrary threshold, or not. That loses a lot of information; why not just keep the click-through rate as a continuous variable? There may be case-specific reasons why you dichotomized the outcome variable, but as a general guidance, this is not considered "best practice". ANd with a continuous variable, you would have a larger choice of statistical tests to chose from.

Thanks so much for posting your insights @jginestet! I appreciate it. The A/B test design to test if the items reached a threshold is a goal specific to our project.

Do you recall by any chance a link or an article that you've read in the past that employed such methodology in A/B tests (random split per user and statistic aggregation by item)? I'm curious to read more about this and to solidify my knowledge on the topic

If you read my answer, I explained that you are not splitting per user, but per design (users are randomly assigned to a design, A or B), and you are aggregating per design (you count all the items which reached a threshold, per design). So the problem you thought you had is not there. You randomly assign users to design A or B, and you measure a variable of interest per design; vanilla A/B testing. I randomly assign subjects to 2 treatments (vaccine/placebo), and I measure the # of infections per treatment. Nothing to worry about...

I needed a minute to wrap my head around what you wrote. After reading "vaccine/placebo" it dawned on me that this is indeed a usual A/B test design. Counting the items on a website that reached / didn't reach a certain threshold is the same idea as counting the number of patients for which a drug was effective / not effective. Thank you!

If this was helpful, feel free to upvote.

Very nice answer, surprising that there are no votes for it ! Well, there is one now :)  OP would not have been able to upvote due to insufficient reputation (but they can as of now). @da-veed I recommend that you upvote this answer and, for the benefit of future users, to accept it (by clicking on the tick mark).

Indeed, thanks for the tip. Upvoted and accepted the answer!
